# How to render the response API with Flatlist in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have some issue with a Flatlist,
I need to render the response data from API in a Flatlist but it doesn't work! 
but when I set the static data it works fine! and when i logging the { item } i don't show anything in Debugging! i think the syntax of Flatlist it's right! 
anybody, can you help me with this issue?

mycode here

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  ScrollView,
  Image,
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
  ListItem
} from "react-native";
import Moment from "react-moment";

import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/dist/FontAwesome";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ApiKeyRef = "****";

    this.watchPositionOpts = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 20000,
      maximumAge: 1000,
      distanceFilter: 5
    };
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      dataSource: [],
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      error: null

    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
      this.watchPositionSuccess,
      this.watchPositionFail,
      this.watchPositionOpts
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchId);
    navigator.geolocation.stopObserving();
  }

  watchPositionSuccess = position => {
    this.setState(
      {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        error: null
      },
      () => this.fetchCallback()
    );
  };

  watchPositionFail = err => {
    this.setState({ error: err.message });
  };

  fetchCallback = async () => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;
    const req = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&units=metric&appid=${
      this.ApiKeyRef
    }`;
    const callback = responseJson => {
      // console.log(responseJson);
      // console.log(responseJson.city.name);
    };

    await fetch(req)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson =>
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, dataSource: responseJson }, () =>
          callback(responseJson)
        )
      )
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

  render() {
    const { dataSource } = this.state;

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }

    const icon =
      dataSource.list[0].main.temp <= 20
        ? require("./assets/cloudySun.png")
        : require("./assets/sunny.png");

    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.head}>
          <Text style={styles.titleApp}>Weather App</Text>

        </View>

        <View style={styles.searchSection}>
          <Icon
            style={styles.searchIcon}
            name="search"
            size={15}
            color="#333"
          />

          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Find Your City.."
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={styles.details}>

{console.log(this.state.dataSource.city.name)} // I get the City name 
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <Text>
                {item.message}, {item.city.name}
    {console.log(item)} // NO Output
              </Text>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          />

        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **extraData** props to FlatList. extraData is used for re-render the FlatList. [extraData](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist#extradata)

Maybe it will help you.

```
           <FlatList
                data={dataSource}
                extraData={this.state} //for re-render the Flatlist data item
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                  <Text>
                    {item.message}, {item.city.name}
                  </Text>
                )}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
              />
```

convert object response to the array

```
      await fetch(req)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson =>{
            let data = [];
            data.push(responseJson); //convert object response to array
            this.setState({ isLoading: false, dataSource: data }, () =>
              callback(data)
            )}
          )
          .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

you also have to change your logic for icons in render method:

```
const icon =
      dataSource[0].list[0].main.temp <= 20
        ? require("./assets/cloudySun.png")
        : require("./assets/sunny.png");
```

Comment: That's work when I set the Data props of Flatlist to the response of array like this **data={this.state.dataSource.list}** because they will loop of them to render I think but it's work now if you have any idea Other than this tell me Bro !

Comment: can you please share your response?

Comment: it's happening because FlatList expects an array and response which are you getting and store in this.state.dataSource is an object. Please convert this object or response in the array and pass it into this.state.dataSource. Maybe it's working

Comment: I'm really doing that, store the response in the state like this **dataSource: []**, so ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. please check it. maybe this will solve your problem.

Comment: thank u man, can you check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53838539/how-to-get-data-for-weather-for-hourly-day-openweathermap-api-by-react-native ?