# How to get data for weather for hourly day, OpenWeatherMap API by react native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, redux

I use OpenWeatherMap API **5 days 3/ hour plan** and I need to get just the hourly weather I use this endpoint

```
 const req = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&cnt=9&units=metric&appid=${
      this.ApiKeyRef
    }`;
```

when I read the Doc of API the parameter **cnt=8** that Cover the all hourly of the day in the 12:00 Am to 12:00 pm, but the issue if I open the App in the night lets say 9:00 pm they will Get the next hourly Day To complete the **cnt=8**!

anyone have an idea to get just the hours in currently Day, if can you help me with this issue?

my Code :

```
fetchCallback = async () => {
    const { latitude, longitude } = this.state;
    const req = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}&cnt=9&units=metric&appid=${
      this.ApiKeyRef
    }`;
    const callback = responseJson => {
      // console.log(responseJson);
      // console.log(responseJson.city.name);
    };

    await fetch(req)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson =>
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, dataSource: responseJson }, () =>
          callback(responseJson)
        )
      )
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };

render(){
return (
 <View style={styles.details}>
          <Text>Hourly</Text>
          <FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource.list}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            horizontal={true}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={[styles.statusWeather]}>
                <Image
                  resizeMode="center"
                  style={[
                    styles.ImgWeek,
                    {
                      width: 110,
                      height: 110,

                      alignSelf: "center"
                    }
                  ]}
                  source={require("./assets/cloudySun.png")}
                />
                <View style={{ alignItems: "center" }}>
                  <Text
                    style={[
                      styles.TextStatus,
                      { fontSize: 19, padding: 0, color: "#263461" }
                    ]}
                  >
                    <Moment element={Text} format="dddd hh:mm A">
                      {item.dt_txt}
                    </Moment>
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={[styles.TextStatus, { padding: 0 }]}>
                    A {item.weather[0].main}
                  </Text>
                  <Text style={styles.TextStatus}>
                    <Text style={{ color: "#263461" }}>
                      {item.main.temp_max}°
                    </Text>
                    <Text> | {item.main.temp_min} °</Text>
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
          />
        </View>
);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript for time left in the day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380687/javascript-for-time-left-in-the-day)

Comment: @chrisg86 nope, that's a different man!

Comment: @chrisg86 can you explain that, please I'm stuck?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, then I misunderstood your question. You might have to edit your question and rephrase it. I don't really know what it is you're asking for.

Comment: @chrisg86 thank you man, I'm waiting for any charm help me :(